# How do I fetch records matching output of aggregate function in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have queried mongodb by using aggregate function and got two fields in the output. 
The result of my db.Collection.aggregate(..) looks like the below:

```
{ 
  "_id" : NumberLong(203440), 
  "date" : ISODate("2013-05-11T00:00:00Z")
}
{ 
  "_id" : NumberLong(203520), 
  "date" :ISODate("2013-01-05T00:00:00Z") 
} 
{ 
  "_id" : NumberLong(203970),
  "date": ISODate("2013-01-11T00:00:00Z") 
} 
{ 
  "_id" : NumberLong(203660),
  "date" : ISODate("2013-01-11T00:00:00Z")
} 
{ 
  "_id" : NumberLong(203360), 
  "date" : ISODate("2013-01-11T00:00:00Z")
}
```

How do I get the records in the collection for which these two fields are true?(in a single query)

i.e If each record in my collection has the fields data,_id, x, y, z, a , b and c,
how do I fetch list of records for which the date and _id are equal to the above result of aggregate?

Comment: The value in the aggregation result "_id" is actually the field x in the document.

Comment: Please show the original document and the aggregation pipeline you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

In the aggregation command, using the below in the $group part helped me.

"allFields": {
                "$first": "$$CURRENT"
            }

In my response, I got the entire document in "allFields" field.